# Come si chiama un investimento su di un bene che perde valore nel tempo?

Tags: word-choice

Se compro un bene che si svaluta nel tempo, con l'intento di fare un investimento, quindi per guadagnarci rivendendolo ad un prezzo più alto, che tipo di investimento sto facendo? Come posso definire questo tipo di investimento con un termine tecnico in italiano?

## Edit

A seguito delle incomprensioni tenterò di chiarire meglio la domanda, fornendo un po' di contesto:

> In economia per investimento si intende l'attività finanziaria di un soggetto economico detto investitore atta all'incremento di beni capitali e l'acquisizione o creazione di nuove risorse da usare nel processo produttivo **al fine ultimo di ottenere un maggior profitto futuro**.

Nel caso specifico stiamo parlando di **"speculazioni"**: compro un bene oggi per rivenderlo ad un prezzo più alto domani.
Ecco alcuni esempi: se negli anni '50 avessi comprato i campi dove verrà costruito l'EXPO di Milano adesso li avrei potuti rivendere ad un prezzo molto, molto più alto del loro valore iniziale. Altri esempi: se avessi comprato i quadri di Van Gogh quando era sconosciuto o la prima edizione de "Il piccolo principe", in tutti questi casi avrei fatto un **investimento su di un bene che acquista valore nel tempo**.
Come posso definire con un termine tecnico un investimento su di un bene che invece perde valore nel tempo? Per esempio se acquistassi quaranta iMac o quaranta Panda da rivendere fra dieci anni o una casa (sempre per rivenderla) su un terreno adiacente ad uno dove verrà costruita una discarica. Certamente sto facendo un pessimo investimento, questo è tuttavia legato al fatto che l'oggetto che sto acquistando perderà il suo valore nel tempo invece di acquistarlo come vorrei. Ipotizziamo che io voglia avvisare un mio cliente:

> « Non le conviene comprare quaranta iMac adesso per rivenderli fra dieci anni perché, fra dieci anni, saranno obsoleti. Farebbe un pessimo investimento su dei beni che perdono valore nel tempo: quello che in gergo viene chiamato … »

Comment: investimento a perdere

Comment: @rosco grazie comunque era giusto anche il commento precedente una volta risistemato, riassumendo si potrebbe dire "un investimento a perdere" o "un investimento su un bene oggetto di deprezzamento"? Aspetto la tua risposta...

Comment: 'investimento a perdere' puo' essere attribuito anche ad una persona. 'investimento su un bene oggetto di deprezzamento' e' piu' preciso, riferendosi appunto ad un bene materiale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un investimento che perde valore nel tempo (a causa del tempo e/o del progresso tecnologico) si definisce come un investimento "che soffre di obsolescenza".

Un investimento, di per se e senza alcun appellativo, presuppone che tu lo stia facendo a fini lucrativi. In genere se non sono presenti fini lucrativi viene specificato (ad. es. "è un investimento per l'umanità").

Se parli nello specifico di un investimento in cui vuoi guadagnare rivendendolo ad un prezzo più alto, allora tecnicamente è un investimento in cui tu vuoi guadagnare "in conto capitale" o più semplicemente "sulla differenza tra il valore di mercato ed il prezzo d'acquisto (o valore storico)".

Answer (score 2):

A seguito dei chiarimenti apportati al testo della domanda, rimuovo il contenuto della mia risposta precedente e ne tento una nuova. Ho anche rimosso vari commenti precedenti che mi sembra non siano più utili.

Se l'esito disastroso dell'investimento è facilmente prevedibile si può parlare semplicemente di:

> cattivo investimento (bad investment)
>
> investimento suicida (suicidal investment)

In caso opposto si può parlare di:

> investimento fallimentare (unsuccessful investment)
>
> investimento infruttuoso

Answer (score 1):

La domanda dà adito ad ambiguità: i beni materiali normalmente si svalutano nel tempo, quindi è difficile trovare un termine per descrivere questa situazione ordinaria.
In questo caso si parla di investimenti reali o *produttivi*, che comprendono anche l'assumere persone, ad esempio.

Poi ci sono gli investimenti *commerciali* in cui si compra un bene rale unicamente per rivenderlo.

Forse ti riferisci agli investimenti *finanziari*, ad esempio investimenti azionari (azioni) o finanziari in genere (finanza derivata, obbligazioni e altro).
In questo caso non è corretto dire che si svaluta. Tale termine è associato ai beni materiali (che come detto si svalutano tutti).
Altri termini che potrebbero andare, se vuoi riferirti agli investimenti finanziari, potrebbero essere:

- infruttuoso
- improduttivo
- sbagliato
- a perdere
- svantaggioso
- vano

Infine, tanto per dare una breve visione della complessità che si può nascondere dietro alla domanda generica che hai posto, bisognerebbe capire cosa intendi quando dici "si svaluta".
La svalutazione è infatti definita rispetto a dei parametri:

- si può svalutare rispetto al *tempo*, quando qualcosa che hai comprato oggi a `X` domani vale `X-1`;
- si può svalutare rispetto *all'inflazione* (ovvero, il valore assoluto del bene aumenta da `X` a `X+1`, ma se l'inflazione passa da *X* a *X+100* si è comunque subita una perdita);
- al tasso di cambio (nella tua valuta potrebbe passare da `X` a `X-1`, ma se la valuta aumenta di valore rispetto ad un'altra allora sei comunque in una situazione vantaggiosa);
- rispetto ad altri beni (potrebbe essere che il valore delle tue azioni, ad esempio, passa da `X` a `X-1`, ma poiché tutti le altre hanno subito un tracollo, la tua situazione è comunque vantaggiosa) .

Ancora una volta il signor Treccani ci viene in aiuto con la [definizione di investimento](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/investimento/):  il termine che cerchi tu è probabilmente **I. IMPRODUTTIVO**

Comment: grazie ma per esempio un quadro di Picasso non credo che si svaluti nel tempo anzi, lo stesso per uno Stradivari ma anche per un appartamento in centro a Milano comprato al momento giusto. Un investimento per definizione non dovrebbe perdere valore nel tempo anzi! Per svaluta intendo che perde valore, se quando lo comprato potevo barattarlo con 500 pagnotte di pane e adesso lo posso barattare con 1 per me ha perso valore. Concedimi che il pane mantenga un valore constante per piacere :-)

Comment: C'è un problema di "vocabolario". L'investimento non perde valore, sono i beni che (eventualmente) perdono valore. 
La domanda che poni è ambigua perché l'azione di "comprare qualcosa che si svaluta col tempo" non è di per sé un investimento.E' la normalità della vita quotidiana (i calzini che compriamo perdono valore col tempo).
Una formulazione più corretta potrebbe essere "Come posso chiamare un investimento che non mi porta al guadagno desiderato"?
Treccani [ci viene in aiuto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/investimento/): il termine che cerchi tu è probabilmente "improduttivo".

Comment: Grazie, ho provato a togliere l'ambiguità...

Answer (score 0):

Se capisco il senso della domanda, al di là della ineccepibile risposta di @Daniele, penso che la parola corretta sia "fregatura" o, quale alternativa piuttosto volgare, "inculata".

> Sono rovinato; l'investimento presso di loro è stata una vera "fregatura"!
>
> Cazzo che "inculata" quell'investimento in borsa! Mi hanno tolto anche le mutande, maremma maiala!

Si noti che il secondo esempio deve essere evitato in conversazioni formali; e sebbene il primo sia accettabile, se chi ascolta è istruito penserà di essere di fronte ad un ignorante.

Così, lì, se si vogliono evitare cattive figure, è prudente usare "cantonata" piuttosto che "fregatura".

> Perbacco, che "cantonata" quell'investimento!

Comment: Grazie della risposta, in realtà pensavo più ad un termine tecnico! Grazie comunque!